# Angular redirecting to an earlier url after http 404 is thrown inside a component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-httpclient

Apologies, could not think of a better question Title to explain the issue.

**Setup**

- Angular application hosted at: http://localhost:4200 (Home page is served by the HomeComponent and displays a button which allows to signin via 3rd party using OAUTH)
- Routing:

  ```
  {
      path:'',
      component:HomeComponent
  }, {
      path:'callback',
      component:CallbackComponent
  }, {
      path: 'show-account',
      component: ShowAccountComponent
  }, {
      path: 'create-account',
      component: CreateAccountComponent
  }
  ```
- After successful signin, the 3rd party IDM redirects to "http://localhost:4200/callback"
- Callback component gets the token etc, stores it in local and verifies if the user already exists in the backend (REST API call to the backend)
- Backend REST API throws (404) to represent a missing User account. 200 OK to return a existing account
- It all works fine if the response from backend HTTP rest service is 200 OK (i.e. the callback component further redirects to ShowAccountComponent.

**Problem**

If the account does not exist in the backend store, the REST API throws back a 404, which is caught by the angular code and the app is further redirected to the CreateAccountComponent.

However, just after this, I observe that the app is again attempting to call the /callback route and again going through the 'capture the token and store in local' flow. Since now there is no more token in the browser url (location.href), it fails while reading token etc.

I am unable to understand why the application is again attempting to go back to callback route in case of HTTP 404 (actually this is happening for any HTTP non-200 response).

I feel there is some HttpClient behaviour in case of non-200 status code, which I am not aware of OR not able to understand.

Any help is appreciated to resolve the above issue.

**Update**

Here is the code where the backendservice is being called to check if the account exists

```
async getUserAccountFromStore(loggedInUserAccount: UserAccount): Promise<UserAccount> {
try {
  let asyncResult = await this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/user?email=" + loggedInUserAccount.email, { observe: 'response' }).toPromise();

  if (asyncResult.status == 200) {
    let accountsArray = asyncResult.body;
    let userAccount = new UserAccount();
    userAccount.name = accountsArray[0].name;
    userAccount.email = accountsArray[0].email;
    userAccount.userProfile = accountsArray[0].profile;
    this.userAccount = userAccount;

    return this.userAccount;
  }
} catch (error) {
  // when the http 404 occurs (will add handling for 500 etc later)
  return undefined;
}
```

}

Comment: Authenticatino usually works with a callback URL, whether if the authentication is success or failure. If you get access token as part of redirect. You can consider the login is success and redirect to user account page. If not redirect to Create Account Page. So both this logic should be added in callback Component.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Thanks for your comment. The problem is not happening because of authentication failure or success. The issue is seen post authentication when retrieving details of the user from backend. A 404 from the backend for the user's account (based on email) is causing the above issue